# how to prove $f^\prime(x)$ is not bounded?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

$f$ is a differentiable function in $(0, 1)$. The limit $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)$ doesn't exist. Prove that $f^\prime(x)$ is not bounded in $(0, 1)$.

I can see why it's true, but I am struggling proving it.
I hope you guys can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Use MVT. If $x_n \to 0+$ show that $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: But to use MVT, I need the function to be continuous in $[0,1]$, and the limit $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x)$ doesn't exist.am I missing something?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That particular claim need not be true. Consider $\sin 1/x$.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. I am suggesting a  proof by contradicton. If $f'$ is bounded then we can show that $\lim f(x)$ exists using MVT.

Answer (score 0):

Put $\alpha=\limsup_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x), \beta = \liminf_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)$.

We may choose strictly decreasing sequences $a_n, b_n \to 0^{+}$ with $a_n \neq b_n$ for each $n$, and with $f(a_n) \to \alpha, f(b_n) \to \beta$. Note the former condition implies $a_n - b_n \to 0$. Hence $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{f(a_n) - f(b_n)}{a_n - b_n}\right| = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \overbrace{|\alpha - \beta|}^{>0}\left|\frac{1}{a_n - b_n}\right| = +\infty$$

and the result follows from the MVT.

Comment: First of all,thanks for the great answer!